# Visual Studio suggesting web.config version redirect but why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, visual-studio-2022

my Visual Studio 2022 is seing version conflict when there should be none, e.g. for Newtonsoft.Json which I only include in Version 13.0.1 as that's the version used by the CMS I'm developing for. So by all I know, everything should reference exactly this version.

Why is Visual Studio suggesting to create a web.config with an assemblybinding containing a version redirect?

I've searched for "Newtonsoft.Json" in my entire solution and found no project referencing another version.

I've tried resharper, NDepend and Dependencies to see if any 3rd party libraries reference another version of Newtonsoft.Json but was unable to find proof of that.

I could just let Visual Studio create these web.config files, but as I have a lot of projects in the solution I would like to get away without them, as they can have merge conflicts (I'm currently working on an upgrade) and they need to be set to contenttype=none to not disturb the web.config in the webroot. I think I could disable the Visual Studio warning but I want to try to get to the bottom of this.

How can I find out what's happening here?

Comment: This problem does not seem to be relation to VS itself, it may have something to do with Newtonsoft.Json itself. What does it suggest for your binding code? What version is redirected to? If you add the 13.0.1 version directly, will there be an error in compilation?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT My solution is set up with web.config files that get deployed and a lot of projects that shouldn't deploy a a web.config file. As the web.config file shouldn't get deployed as it might overwrite the correct one I would prefer to have only web.config files that get deployed as they are a source of headache. During runtime the application has a web.config with a version redirect so I only want a clean warning list in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

A couple possibilities.

1. If you are using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema that will by default try to work with Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0.x.  That could be one reason to require a binding redirect.
2. A second reason is just that Newtonsoft.Json version 12.x had bad security issues, so it makes sense to only have your app work with 13.x.

Besides doing a search of your system to look for conflicting versions, you can also check programmatically which versions are getting pulled in by checking

```
Assembly[] loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

and checking the Assembly.FullName and  Assembly.Location

Comment: I don't worry about runtime, as for runtime I have a web.config in place that has the version redirect. I just want to avoid having version redirects and web.config files in each project, as the solution is set up with a lot of projects. Each existing web.config might overwrite the correct web.config if not set to buildaction none, so I would like to have no web.configs except the ones I want to deploy.